# Handling Popups in Selenium phantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, popup, phantomjs, web-crawler

I'm building a web crawler in python selenium phantomJS that visits links, takes a screenshot of the entire webpage, and saves it to AWS s3. Unfortunately, on certain sites, I get stuck at a "please sign up for our newsletter" popup and despite my best efforts, cannot find a solution for dismissing it. Here's what it looks like:

[image: oop up example]

From their documentation (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.alert), I've tried alert, but it doesn't seem to do the job. I need to handle both HTML and javascript generated popups.

Here's an abbreviated example of the code I'm working with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1600, 1200)) # Xvfb headless display
display.start()
capabilities = {'handlesAlerts': 'True'}
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://www.everlane.com/products/mens-slim-fit-oxford-shirt2-grey?collection=mens-shirt-shop')
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
driver.save_screenshot()
```

I've also tried:

`driver.switch_to_default_content()`

Keypad "ESC", "ENTER", "F4" don't work either.

I can locate the element's XPath and click to dismiss, but need a general purpose solution because I'm working with more than one site and therefore more than one XPath.

Any help would be much appreciated! I can't be the only one with this problem so I hope others find this useful. Thanks.